# How to disassociate the Bluetooth connection for a Magic Trackpad 2 from macOS?

Tags: bluetooth, trackpad, monterey, magic-trackpad

I have a Magic Trackpad 2 that's been having some intermittent slowdown when connected normally. After turning off Bluetooth generally on macOS the Magic Trackpad 2 works great all of the time with no lag/slowdown.

Clearly the problem is with the Bluetooth connection having some kind of interference or such and so I'd like to operate it with the USB cable (as I already have it plugged in 100% of the time anyway) only.

How can I, therefore, permanently disassociate a Magic Trackpad 2 device once it's been paired with macOS?

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to **System Preferences → Bluetooth**
2. Right click the Magic Trackpad
3. Click **Remove**

Comment: Would be great if that worked - that just does not function as such. I can do that for other Bluetooth devices but NOT the `Magic Trackpad 2`.

Comment: @ylluminate were you able to resolve this? I'm experiencing the same thing

Comment: Sadly no @Alex...